# Read only filesystem (/dev/sda7) and booting into intrafms. (WIndows 10 dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, filesystem, read-only

Whenever I try to boot into Ubuntu I get the `Intrafms` prompt. I have found that I can fix it using
`fsck /dev/sda7`, say yes to all the troubleshooting prompts, and when that finishes I use`exit`. This tends to get me into Ubuntu normally most of the time. However sometimes I am greeted with multiple error message saying {file} is not writable, contact your administrator for details, and when I try to boot Discord (Discord has became my "Canary" for filesystem programs because it likes to write temporary directories) the terminal responds by saying that it cannot create necessary directories because /dev/sda7 is ReadOnly.

---

### what I have tried

1. **Booting into recovery mode.** 
   When I boot into recovery mode, I am first met with the `intrafms` prompt and `/dev/sda7 contains a filesystem with errors. preforming check /dev/sda7 |=========>     | 25% complete`
   and then when it finishes the check it tells me that /de/sda7 requires a manual fsck. Then I continue as if I were booting into normal mode. Then I am met with a typical recovery mode screen that often tells me that my filesystem is read-only. Thankfully I can mount /dev/sda7 in read/write using the check filesystem tool in the recovery menu. Then I continue the boot  but when I reboot to get my full graphics drivers back I am back where I started
2. **using the disk utility**.
   I have tried looking at the disk tool in Ubuntu and this is the result:

```
Model: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF100 (JU001C)
Size: 1.0 TB (1,000,204,886,016 bytes)
Partitioning: GUID Partition Table
Serial Number: 6827CUSFT
Assessment: Disk is OK, 4264 bad sectors (35° C / 95° F)
```

It also tells me that /dev/sda7 is using `ext4 (Version 1.0)` and I also have a unused 225GB partition (/dev/sda6).

I will update this question when I try a new fix or get new important information.

**EDIT 1**: I am also getting the following notifications repeatedly even though other programs are working:

```
Configuration file "/home/asher/.config/kio_httprc" not writable.
Please contact your system administrator.
```

```
Configuration file "/home/potatoes/.config/kded5rc" not writable.
Please contact your system administrator.
```

I also did a spelling and grammar check

**EDIT 2:** after a little while in normal Ubuntu the filesystem reverts back to read-only. I don't know why this occurred.

**EDIT 3:**

[SMART test results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssLpB.png)

this is the output for    `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`

```
Binary file /var/log/syslog matches
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 11:22:37 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [33451.806034] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 11:22:37 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [33451.806059] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 11:22:37 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [33451.806079] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 16:33:43 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [50291.446008] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 16:33:49 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [50297.493682] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 16:33:50 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [50297.885180] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 17:23:44 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [53291.812459] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 17:23:44 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [53291.812483] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 17:23:44 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [53291.812503] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 17:23:44 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [53291.812516] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 17:23:44 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [53291.812534] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 17:39:42 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [54250.146483] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
grep: /var/log/syslog.1: Input/output error
```

**EDIT 4:** suggestion worked but I will leave you with a parting message from a SMART test:
`Overall Assessment: Disk is OK, 4663 bad sectors` thanks for the help!

Comment: It's because it looks like your disk is going bad. Is your important data backed up? Edit your question and show me the `Disks` application **SMART Data** window. It may take two screenshots to capture all of the data in the scrollable window. Also show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: When you supply requested data, make sure that the requester gets notified by sending a comment that starts with @heynnema (in my own example).

Comment: Please see my answer. Try the NCQ patch first. If that doesn't help, then do the bad blocking. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema
The NCQ fix seemed to work! thank you so much for helping me out! now to see how long it holds (hopefully indefininitly)

Comment: Now, backup your important data, and do the bad blocking. Report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**initramfs**

At the `initramfs` prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sda7`.

**NCQ**

You're getting ncq errors on the disk. Let's try a quick patch.

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 22 11:22:37 asher-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-ba1xx kernel: [33451.806034] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**bad blocking**

If the NCQ patch didn't help... if this fails, then your disk is bad...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```